# Spawn prefab in front of UI Image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I spawn the prefab in a gameobject and that gameobject is a child of UI Image what I'm trying to accomplish is display the prefab infront of a UI Image. I've tried making z position of gameobject to negative but nothing happens. I can't place the sorting layer of UI Image cause it doesn't exist. What should I do? Is this even possible?

[image]

**Update**

Tried adding second camera. I made gameobject layer to SecondCam. Change settings of second camera to depth only and it's culling mask to SecondCam only then it's layer to SecondCam also. Change settings of main camera culling mask to everything except SecondCam. But this doesn't work, Have I done something wrong?
[image]

**Second Camera settings**
[image]

**Main Camera settings**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your Gameobject is not one of the UI components you may need to give it another layer and render it with another camera with depth property higher than the UI camera.

You can change the sorting layer on prefabs or any object created on runtime.

Comment: "Give it another layer and render it with another camera with depth property higher than the UI camera" I'm confuse about this one is there a tutorial about this one?

Comment: Please check Unity documentation on layers and cameras. Everything is explained there. Unity has great number of tutorials online.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Kindly check my main post. Thanks

Comment: Renderer has this rendererPriority property, have you tried changing it?

Answer (score 0):

If your UI canvas is set to screen overlay, then it with *ALWAYS* render on top. You have to use a screen space or world space UI, along with Dave's answer.